# How to create message queues by using JNI in android app

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am new to android app development, I want to create two services, these services must communicate with each other by using a message queue.

For this purpose, i have to call low-level kernel functions by using JNI. How to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JNI to do this? Services can communicate via intents and startService() as recommended in the Android documentation. Alternatively, you can use the [Messenger class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html).